# how to redirect only the posts from my old domain to the same posts in the new domain? .htacess?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Please tell me how to redirect only the posts (not the categories and not the homepage) of my old domain to the new domain.

i have tried everything i can (in .htacess) 
like this:
[first thing i tried](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8596483/revisions)

or this:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.bg$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.bg/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please please help me. Thank you

Edit: i did try this:

```
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.newdomain.bg/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it redirects all but the homepage. I need to exclude the categories pages too(10 categories) ?
How to exclude other pages from this rule?

Comment: like olddomain.bg/post1 to be redirected to newdomain.bg/post1
i have tried everything :(

Comment: Try working around with your last piece of code - you said it redirects everything but the homepage. You also want to exclude the categories - so why not add `RewriteRule (.+) http://www.novini24.bg/category/$1 [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: because i have tried it and it does not work..
Please suggest something different ?
Thank you in advance for your help