# how to redirect ONLY the posts from old domain to the same posts in new domain? .htacess?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Please tell me how to redirect only the posts (not the categories and not the homepage) of my old domain to the new domain. I want to exclude the categories and the homepage(its just 10 category links www.oldwebsite.com/categoryfirst ... /categorytenth and the homepage.)

i have tried everything i can (in .htacess) 
like this:
[first thing i tried](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8596483/revisions)

or this:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.bg$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.bg/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please please help me. Thank you

Edit: i did try this:

```
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.newdomain.bg/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it redirects all but the homepage. I need to exclude the categories pages too(10 categories) ?
How to exclude other pages from this rule(links or category ... whatever, i just need to exclude 10 of them)?

Also i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154909/how-to-redirect-only-the-posts-from-my-old-domain-to-the-same-posts-in-the-new-d?noredirect=1#comment87364979_50154909).

Really i have tried various combinations from all of the above... Still nothing works :(

Its a Wordpress website with the theme "Nexus". I can provide the whole htacess file if you need it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you know each url you want to exclude (/categ1/, /foo/ ) you can 
add each in a rewritecond rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.bg$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !categ1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.bg/$1 [L,R=301]
```